# Box API does not return folders being collaborated on

Tags: box-api

I have 2 box enterprise accounts for 2 different domains. Lets call them account A and B. I am the administrator on both of these accounts. From my account A, I invited some users of B to collaborate on some folders. These folders then become visible in account B and the users in B can collaborate on them. The problem is that, this is true only for the Box-UI. When I try to get the contents of B account using API calls, I never get to see those folders in the API response.

For example lets say account A has a folder named `Rob` on its root folder. Now I invite a collaborator from Account B on this folder. The collaboration successfully happens and I can see the folder in account B on the Box-UI. However when I call the Box API for folders on account B, I never get the folder 'Rob'. The `items` endpoint of the folder never returns `Rob`. It however send a `count` of the items which includes this folder(I manually counted the folders in B and the numbers match). This is very confusing. Why is a count being returned whereas no data is being sent along with it. What can I do to get those folders in the API response?....Has this feature been like this from the start of V2 API or some recent changes caused this behavior. I vaguely remember that previously box would return all the folders in the API response(I might be wrong on this one)

Comment: I am using the admin auth-token coupled with the user impersonation feature of `As-User` to get the folders inside a user's directory.

Comment: @peter Any update on this issue? Has this been fixed?

Comment: Sounds like it is likely associated with using as-user capabilities between two admins.  We are looking into it.